# Create user who can only access one directory

Tags: ssh, permissions, users, account-restrictions

I would like to create a user that only has access to one folder and nothing else whatsoever.

I have already created a user but he has access to other parts of the system according to corresponding file settings. I don't want him to have that, I want him only to have access to one folder and nothing else. Everything else should preferably be just invisible to him.

Is it possible to create such a user,and if so, how do I go about doing that?

p.s.
Removing 'other' privileges of other users home directory goes a bit of the way towards this end. But this limited user still has access to all the base directories like /etc and such. And he can still see other users home directory, even though he cant access them.

Comment: what *nix are you in? how is the user going to access the system?

Comment: I'm using L-Ubuntu but intend to also use this for OSX. This limited user will access via ssh.

Comment: What does he need ssh for? Is it to upload files, or to attempt to issue commands or some other purpose?

Comment: It's to run rsync via ssh on that one folder.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, you can. I never tried it myself, but  [`jailkit`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/jailkit) seems to fit the bill. It doesn't seem to have been pre-packaged for Debian, so your only option is to [build from source](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/index.html#download) if you're on Debian or any of its children.

Thanks to @terdon's comment, we know it's been packaged as RPM and as a source package for Arch.

@terdon's links:

- [RPM package](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=jailkit&submit=Search+...)
- [Arch source package on the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jailkit/)

From @slm's comment, a [note](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92856/how-to-install-jailkit) on installing `jailkit` from source.

**Update**

Since you indicate in your comments that you're planning to give this user access via SSH, these additional articles may be of value to you:

- [Chroot users with OpenSSH](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/chroot-users-with-openssh-an-easier-way-to-confine-users-to-their-home-directories/)
- [How to chroot ssh user using Jailkit](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=248724)

Comment: What makes you think it has not been packaged? Granted, there seems to be no .deb but you can find RPMs of jailkit [here](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=jailkit&submit=Search+...), and an arch source package [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jailkit/).

Comment: Here's some info about jailkit from askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92856/how-to-install-jailkit. There's a PPA available, `ppa:jailkit/ppa`.

Answer (score 3):

If rsync is your one and only use case, you may want to think about simply exposing an rsync server that the user can connect to directly.

[A very detailed explanation for rsync + stunnel](http://www.netbits.us/docs/stunnel_rsync.html)

[This is how you would access that service](http://www.bytemark.co.uk/support/technical_documents/backuprsyncssl?tags=)

If you insist on SSH you could just disable login by setting that users shell to `/bin/false`, which would still allow you to use SSH as tunnel through which you could make your rsync connection work, [as described here](https://serverfault.com/questions/56566/ssh-tunneling-only-access)